# Kendo Grid Hierarchy (child) grid on click event

Tags: kendo-ui, grid

I want to add Hierarchy (child) grid on button click event. By default on grid load, there is a child grid. I want it to bind on button click.

```
var people = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      data: {!Output},
      batch: true,
      schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    carId: { type: "string" },
                    vehicleId: { type: "string", editable:false  },
                    Percentage: { type: "number", editable:false  },
                    Price: { type: "string", editable:false},
                    CarType: { type: "string", editable:false},
                    CarSize: { type: "string", editable:false},
                    CarPerCase: { type: "number", editable:false },
                    Family: { type: "string", editable:false},
                    ModelType: { type: "string", editable:false},
                    EPId: { type: "string" }, 
                    Tax: { type: "string" }
                }
            }
        },
      pageSize: 20,
      sort: { field: "vehicleId", dir: "asc" }
    });    
var element = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: people,
        navigatable: true,
        pageable: true, 
        toolbar: [
            "save", 
            "cancel",
             {
                name: "Add",
                text: "Show Car Price",
                click: function(e) {                         
                    return false;
                }
             },
             {
                name: "Delete",
                text: "Hide Car Price",
                click: function(e) {                         
                    return false;
                }
             }
        ],
        columns:[                  
              {
                  field: "carId",
                  title: "Car ID",
                  width: 150,  
                  hidden:true                    
              },
              {
                  field: "vehicleId",
                  title: "Vehicle ID",
                  width: 100
              },
              {
                  field: "Percentage",
                  title: "Percentage",
                  width: 70
              },
              {
                  field: "Price",
                  title: "Price",
                  width: 250
              },
              {
                  field: "CarType",
                  title: "Car Type"
              },
              {
                  field: "CarSize",
                  title: "Car Size"
              },
              {
                  field: "CarPerCase",
                  title: "Car Per Case"
              },
              {
                  field: "Family",
                  title: "Family"
              },
              {
                  field: "ModelType",
                  title: "Model Type",
                  width: 100
              },
              {
                  field: "EPId",
                  title: "EP Id",
                  hidden: false
              },                 
              {
                  field: "Tax",
                  title: "Tax",
                  format: "{0:c}",
                  width: 100
              }
          ],   
          editable:true,                                                                           
         groupable: true,  
         filterable: true,                     
         sortable: true,
         reorderable: true,
         resizable: true,
         columnMenu: true,                          
         pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: [10, 20, 50],
            buttonCount: 5
         },
         editable: "incell",               
         detailInit: detailInit                   
      });
// hierarchy grid
      function detailInit(e) {                 
              var detailRow = e.detailRow;
              codeDetailData = e.data;

            $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({                    
                dataSource: e.data.ItemPrices.toJSON(),                                        
                editable:true,
                navigatable: true,
                scrollable: false,
                sortable: true,
                pageable: true,
                columns: [
                    { 
                        field: "Engine", 
                        width: "200px",
                        editor: serviceItemAutoCompleteEditor   
                    },
                    { 
                        field: "TN", 
                        title:"TN", 
                        width: "110px" 
                    },
                    { 
                        field: "TaxApplied", 
                        title:"Tax Applied" 
                    },
                    { 
                        field: "TaxChange", 
                        title: "Tax Change", 
                        width: "300px" 
                    },
                    { 
                        field: "StartDate", 
                        title: "Start Date",
                        format:"{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", 
                        editor: dateTimeEditor 
                    },
                    { 
                        field: "EndDate", 
                        title: "End Date",
                        format:"{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", 
                        editor: dateTimeEditor  
                    }
                ]
            });

         }
```

Now the detailInit: detailInit configuration is set on load. I want that load without detailInit (responsible for child grid), and bind this setting on button click. Is it possible?

Comment: Provide you code to give a solution

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a detail template to tell the grid there is going to be a detailinit grid

```
var element = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: people,
    navigatable: true,
    toolbar: [
        "save",
        "cancel", {
        name: "Add",
        text: "Show Car Price",
        click: function (e) {
            return false;
        }
    }, {
        name: "Delete",
        text: "Hide Car Price",
        click: function (e) {
            return false;
        }
    }],
    columns: [{
        field: "carId",
        title: "Car ID",
        width: 150,
        hidden: true
    }, {
        field: "vehicleId",
        title: "Vehicle ID",
        width: 100
    }, {
        field: "Percentage",
        title: "Percentage",
        width: 70
    }, {
        field: "Price",
        title: "Price",
        width: 100
    }, {
        field: "CarType",
        title: "Car Type"
    }, {
        field: "CarSize",
        title: "Car Size"
    }, {
        field: "CarPerCase",
        title: "Car Per Case"
    }, {
        field: "Family",
        title: "Family"
    }, {
        field: "ModelType",
        title: "Model Type",
        width: 100
    }, {
        field: "EPId",
        title: "EP Id",
        hidden: false
    }, {
        field: "Tax",
        title: "Tax",
        format: "{0:c}",
        width: 100
    }],
    groupable: true,
    filterable: true,
    sortable: true,
    reorderable: true,
    resizable: true,
    columnMenu: true,
    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: [10, 20, 50],
        buttonCount: 5
    },
    editable: "incell",
    detailTemplate: 'Item Prices: <div class="grid"></div>',
dataBound:function(e){
$(".k-hierarchy-cell").hide();
$(".k-hierarchy-col").hide();
}
});
```

then bind the detail event to the grid using a click button

```
    $("#testbtn").click(function (e) {
         $(".k-hierarchy-cell").show();
        $(".k-hierarchy-col").show();
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.unbind("detailInit");
        grid.bind("detailInit", grid_detailInit);
    grid.refresh();
    });
```

Here is a Jsfiddle Example http://jsfiddle.net/ecotz69h/7/

Comment: Actually I want that this statement [ detailInit: detailInit ] or in the case of your example [ detailTemplate: 'Item Prices: <div class="grid"></div>' ] in code, should not be at the time of loading of grid. So when grid load first time, this statement should not be there. And it should added/bind on button click.

Comment: It means the statement/code responsible for adding hierarchy grid into main grid, should not be there in grid configuration, when grid loads first time. The hierarchy grid should bind / this configuration should bind, to grid at button click

Comment: hmm.. you can manually hide it $(".k-hierarchy-cell").hide();
    $(".k-hierarchy-col").hide(); and show it back . i have update the jsfiddle

Comment: I already done that.But its not giving me solution of my problem.My requirement is complex.It is that main grid should load without hierarchy grid.And a button should bind hierarchy grid on click. Main grid will be navigatable with keyboard.If I bind hierarchy grid on load, then on pressing 'Enter' key, hierarchy grid get expanded.And this should not happen.Also by hiding columns, 'Enter' key on main grid, does not work as expected.Its solution is main grid will load without hierarchy grid and user can navigate on it with keyboard and a button will bind hierarchy grid to main grid on click.

Comment: [Important note] The external resource kendo.all.min.js, used by you, in fiddle, is distributed by kendo in 2012 (v2012.1.322). It is working according to my requirements. But I am using kendo.all.min.js version (v2014.1.528) distributed in 2014. If I use your version, then i have to lose many other functionality in my grid. you can find my version here: http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.528/js/kendo.all.min.js, Please use this version of kendo.all.min.js

Comment: you should clearly mention your requirements when posting the question , and jsfiddle is just to demo you its possible . you can fork it and do any change you like to it. you could capture the enter key press and not load the hierarchy grid using e.preventdefault. sound to me like you have a logic issue

Comment: e.preventdefault will not fit in my requirement. My requirement is complex one. All I want is this statement [ detailInit: detailInit ] Or in your example case [detailTemplate: 'Item Prices: <div class="grid"></div>'] should not be in code at the time of load of gird. This statement is responsible for hierarchy. There should be a button that bind/attach hierarchy grid to main grid on click.

Comment: without it , it's not possible . you have to manually hide or show it